# How to resolve the error in react redux project?

Tags: javascript, react-redux

[Link to the project](https://codesandbox.io/s/would-you-rather-i8z71)

In this react redux project I am trying to add the answers to the users object in the state. But I am getting an error and don't know why I am getting this error and how to resolve it. When I select an option and submit the form it throws an error *Cannot read property 'answers' of undefined*. I don't know how to resolve this error. Please help. The above link to the project opens in code sandbox online editor. If you want to work in your local editor run `npm install` in the command prompt.

Comment: Questions need to stand on their own.

Comment: I am sorry. But I didn't get you. The error occurred deep down in the hierarchy if I post a part of the project may be it do not tell where I am getting the error. That's why I post the link to the whole working project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made a mistake in "reducers/questions.js".
You need to recreate `SAVE_ANSWER_TO_USER` action and reducer.
Here's my sandbox link forked from yours.

https://codesandbox.io/s/would-you-rather-h2o7r

You can confirm the change of answer inside users state.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It resolves the error but it didn't add the answer to the users object in the state. You can check the state in the console window for users object.

Comment: This is **questions** reducer, not **users**. Thus, answers are added into questions now. You can confirm it by logging state inside the action. And If you want to add answer into **users**, you need to add an action and reducer for it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood something this is user reducers question reducer is below it which is SAVE_ANSWER_TO_QUESTION. For more info about the structure of data check out the _DATA.js file in utils folder.

Comment: Take a look at this screenshot. https://prnt.sc/pfc77r As you can see, SAVE_ANSWER_TO_USER actually modifies question, not user.

Comment: Yes you are right. I noticed that. But that's not the functionality that I want. I want to update the users and questions object inside the state when someone submits the answer. Can you please review my code of questions.js inside actions, reducers, and component.js and tell me where I am wrong. I also tried with making separate reducers and actions but the output still remains the same

Comment: Updated answer, visit https://codesandbox.io/s/would-you-rather-h2o7r.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200459/discussion-between-sumit-and-tom-carrier).

Answer (score 0):

Add an ‘alert(“middleware: “ + window.location.path)’ in the code. An object is not defined probably because of a inaccessible path.